# Sort values ASC and then get corresponding value by index of sorted table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do exist query but by using indexing.

So for example, i have multiple answers for given question.

Every answer has it's unique id by which it is being sorted.

[image]

I would use query on the Answers table:

`SELECT Answers.answer_id FROM Answers WHERE Answers.question_id = 2 ORDER BY Answers.answer_id ASC`

which would reply with the rows fulfilling requirement. 
Instead i would like to compare the index of what would be a reponse to what i got.
For example index of 0 which would be a first element and return boolean on it exisitng.

This is what query would reply:

1
2
3

I need to check if the element of the array which is a reply exists.
For example element of index 0 which id is 1.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: your question is not clear  .. try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i did it using `COUNT` which i noticed from the previous answer.
So i am going to add +1 to an index which i got for example 0 and then query and check if the response is longer than the index i got:

`SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM apurer.Answers WHERE apurer.Answers.question_id = 2 ORDER BY apurer.Answers.answer_id ASC`.